# Mongo DB - To get the last data for every unique email address - Grouped by Regions

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
db.TYPE_Join_STEP_COUNTER_GPS.aggregate([
        { $match: { 'Time.ObservationTimestamp': { $gte: ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"),  $lt: ISODate("2019-02-02T00:00:00+00:00") } } },
        {
            $group: {
                _id: { users: "$userAccount.userEmail" },

                sensorValue: { $addToSet: "$sensorValue.sensorValue" }
            }
        },
        {
            $unwind: "$sensorValue"
        },
        {
            $group: { _id: "$_id", lastdata: {$last: "$sensorValue"} }
        }
    ])
```

I got the below output for this query.

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
    "users" : "test1@gmail.com"
},
"lastdata" : "245"
},

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
    "users" : "test2@gmail.com"
},
"lastdata" : "135"
}
```

**What I need** - I need the last data of Sensor value for unique email ids in every region. I tried to add one more group by condition with respect to region but it didnt work. Please let me know if I am missing something. Thank you in advance.

**Sample Collection**:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5c52f5370ad3076c2398ba83"),
"userAccount" : {
    "userId" : "115867679428105538091",
    "userEmail" : "test1@gmail.com"
},
"deviceId" : "9312dfc5b63063c7",
"sensorType" : "TYPE_Join_STEP_COUNTER_GPS",
"sensorValue" : {
    "sensorValue" : "257",
    "regoin" : "Region1"
},
"Time" : {
    "ObservationTimestamp" : ISODate("2019-01-30T00:00:00.000+00:00")
}
}
```

**Expected Output:**

```
/* 1 */
{
"_id" : {
    "regoin" : "Region1"
},
users: "Test1@gmail.com" , "lastdata" : "135"
users: "Test2@gmail.com" , "lastdata" : "105"
},

/* 2 */
{
"_id" : {
    "regoin" : "Region2"
},
users: "Test1@gmail.com" , "lastdata" : "105"
users: "Test2@gmail.com" , "lastdata" : "100"
},
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**`$last`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/last/) accumulator to get the last sensor value

```
db.TYPE_Join_STEP_COUNTER_GPS.aggregate([
  { "$match": {
    "Time.ObservationTimestamp": {
      "$gte": ISODate("2019-01-01T00:00:00+00:00"),
      "$lt": ISODate("2019-02-02T00:00:00+00:00")
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": { "userEmail": "$userAccount.userEmail", "regoin": "$sensorValue.regoin" },
    "sensorValue": { "$last": "$sensorValue.sensorValue" }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id.regoin",
    "data": {
      "$push": {
        "user": "$_id.userEmail",
        "sensorValue": "$sensorValue"
      }
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I have already used $last accumulator in my query. I want to group by this result with respect to the region field. Please let me know if you have any suggestions for the same.

Comment: Please post the sample collection and the output you want

Comment: I have updated my question with the sample collection and the expected output. Please check. Thank you.

Comment: Updated my answer. You can check